# Unity 4 and Vuforia Target object Not Show on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia

I follow all the steps that show on the below movie but my object is not appeared on the phone.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrEnREOT1F0

I did these steps:

1. import vuforia package
2. import target marker package (downloaded from vuforia)
3. removed the main camera an add an ARCamera
4. add an imageTarget and set target marker
5. on the ARCamera checked the Load Data Set and Active from DataSetBehaviour
6. create a GameObject CUBE and put it on the imageTarget (it's big enough)
7. I can see the image marker and cube on the CameraPreview
8. Added defaultTrackableEventHandler to ImageTarget

and published as an Android App.

When I lunch on the phone, the camera started but when I point to image Marker the Cube not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the problem. 
Everything was OK but the Image Marker does not have any more features. It was only a letter A with a bold border which was very weak. I used Tulip photo which is windows sample photo and my app works well.
I answered here just for others that have same problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you make de DataSet notice the stars "ranking" of your image, more stars + more detectable, the device camera also take big part (poco enfoque y calidad de la camara afecta mucho), sorry my english.. salu2 desde el mas alla.

Comment: Please use only english for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make sure the AR camera was close enough to the 3d model in the scene editor.